# Where do we find a LaTeX style/class development expert for hire?

Tags: documentclass-writing

We would like to hire the services of an expert (individual or company) in LaTeX style/class development to modernize the template used in a scientific conference's proceedings.

We are currently using a very old style that doesn't incorporate many of the advances made in the TeX community (no hyperref, document layout, bad interactions with some packages, etc.). This class is used for hundreds of documents, that are typeset by the article authors themselves.

Is there some directory of experts for hire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [TeX Consulting and Production Services](https://www.tug.org/consultants.html) on the TUG homepage.  Other TeX user groups might have similar rosters.

Comment: I was hoping for some more up-to-date directory (listings there seem to be _old_). Thank you for the reference though!

Answer (score 0):

There are some freelancers offering their services on http://www.freelancer.com . Don't know anything about their quality, but you can do look at their profiles for reviews and ratings of their previous work.

For instance have a look at: https://www.freelancer.com/freelancers/skills/latex/

(not affiliated with this website).

Comment: I noticed my answer got downvoted. Probably because of an URL that wasn't added properly. Can you review that?

Comment: The link is added correctly, but I think they downvoted your answer because of _Don't know anything about their quality_  or because it's seen as an advertise...

Comment: hmm okay, it's a proper answer to the question of @Kilburn isn't it? I think it helps them on the way. I can't possibly be aware of the quality of all the freelancers offering their services on that site, so I wanted to add that as a disclaimer. Thanks for your answer though and your edit of the answer.

Comment: The etiquette requires to explain the reason for downvoting, but, unfortunately, some people don't do it :)