# LaTeX Typesetting Service

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

If this is off topic or not allowed please let me know and I will remove it immediately.

I have two sets of documents that I need typeset into LaTeX and graphics computerized (math drawings, graphs, etc).  I don't need them for about another month or so.  Is there anyone on this forum / does anyone know of a typesetter that could do these documents?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430133/35864 as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434451/35864. There is also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6591/35864

Comment: I have done typesetting jobs in the past. My email is in `prooftrees` documentation. [Note that these are simply factual statements, since anything else would probably flout SE's rules. Inferences drawn from these statements are entirely the responsibility of the reader.]